# Neo4j: Can't CREATE a node with nested properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have searched everywhere, but cannot find the answer to this.

I need to create a node `Config` that has a dynamic properties object with 2 key/value pairs (for example, `name` and `type`). The keys, when queried, should end up as `properties.name` and `properties.type`. But I cannot seem to get the create syntax right. This is what I'm doing:

```
CREATE (c1:Config) set c1.properties=[{name:"CiPipelineConfig1"}, {type:"test"}]
```

But that gives me some weird error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Neo4j only supports a subset of Cypher types for storage as singleton or array properties.
```

Can anyone help me figure this query out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neo4j has a limited [property type](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/values/) set.

You should store the values as properties of the node, instead of craming them into one property.

```
// You need the `` around the property name to escape the period
CREATE (c1:Config) set c1.`properties.name`="CiPipelineConfig1" set c1.`properties.type`="test"
```

If this is not good enough for you, you will need to reformat your data to something that is compatible with the Neo4j Types.

Answer (score 2):

One way to create nested properties is using `JSON` property as string property, you can dump and encode data in write and load and decode when read. 
One example of this is [neomodel](https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module_documentation.html#neomodel.properties.JSONProperty) json property in python.

This is code of neomodel json property:

```
class JSONProperty(Property):
    """
    Store a data structure as a JSON string.

    The structure will be inflated when a node is retrieved.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JSONProperty, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @validator
    def inflate(self, value):
        return json.loads(value)

    @validator
    def deflate(self, value):
        return json.dumps(value)
```

Comment: Note that storing JSON strings in Neo4j is discouraged, because it is technically blob data, and neo4j can't store blob data (large strings) efficiently. So this will degrade your DB in the long run. If your data set is small however, you can get away with this.

Comment: @Tezra Why it will degrade db? do you have any link to explain it?

Comment: It is technically a problem with all databases that are not meant to act as file stores. Because it is stored as a blob, the db can't efficiently search on that information. (If you store as a byte array, the db can't search against it at all) Because it is a less efficient way to store the data, it requires more space on disk, and with large data, those inefficiencies will become quite noticeable. Particularly on RAM requirements while querying the data. (And especially if you can't shard the DB)

Comment: But since the data is useless to the DB in this format, it is a good sign you actually want a config file on disk to read from.

Comment: @Tezra, What if I don't search on that field? Suppose I have user with unique username to match on that, then I get some json data from another filed of that user node?

Comment: Just for reference, if you have the a long property, and assuming pointers are longs for simplicity, that is a 32 bit pointer to property + 32 bit value = 64 bits. A char is 8 bits so 64/8=4. Max long is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 which is 19 chars. If your data-set is small enough, there really is no reason to care about performance; You will never notice this. Once you start to scale though, String is an extremely inefficient storage format. And the larger your property names/values, the more inefficient it is. I'm not saying you can't do this, just keep it in mind if you need to scale.