# Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof in Neo4J Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following `params` set:

```
:params "userId":"15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9",
"contextNames":[{"uid":"94e71bf0-1e7d-11e9-8f33-4f0c99ea0da1","name":"zhora"}],
"statements":[{"text":"oranges apples bananas","concepts":["orange","apple","banana"],
"mentions":[],"timestamp":15481867295710000,"name":"# banana","uid":"34232870-1e7f-11e9-8609-a7f6b478c007",
"uniqueconcepts":[{"name":"orange","suid":"34232870-1e7f-11e9-8609-a7f6b478c007","timestamp":15481867295710000},{"name":"apple","suid":"34232870-1e7f-11e9-8609-a7f6b478c007","timestamp":15481867295710000},{"name":"banana","suid":"34232870-1e7f-11e9-8609-a7f6b478c007","timestamp":15481867295710000}],"uniquementions":[]}],"timestamp":15481867295710000,"conceptsRelations":[{"from":"orange","to":"apple","context":"94e71bf0-1e7d-11e9-8f33-4f0c99ea0da1","statement":"34232870-1e7f-11e9-8609-a7f6b478c007","user":"15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9","timestamp":15481867295710000,"uid":"apoc.create.uuid()","gapscan":"2","weight":3},{"from":"apple","to":"banana","context":"94e71bf0-1e7d-11e9-8f33-4f0c99ea0da1","statement":"34232870-1e7f-11e9-8609-a7f6b478c007","user":"15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9","timestamp":15481867295710002,"uid":"apoc.create.uuid()","gapscan":"2","weight":3},{"from":"orange","to":"banana","context":"94e71bf0-1e7d-11e9-8f33-4f0c99ea0da1","statement":"34232870-1e7f-11e9-8609-a7f6b478c007","user":"15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9","timestamp":15481867295710002,"uid":"apoc.create.uuid()","gapscan":4,"weight":2}],"mentionsRelations":[]
```

Then when I make the following query:

```
MATCH (u:User {uid: $userId}) 
UNWIND $contextNames as contextName 
MERGE (context:Context {name:contextName.name,by:u.uid,uid:contextName.uid}) 
ON CREATE SET context.timestamp=$timestamp 
MERGE (context)-[:BY{timestamp:$timestamp}]->(u) 
WITH u, context 
UNWIND $statements as statement 
CREATE (s:Statement {name:statement.name, text:statement.text, uid:statement.uid, timestamp:statement.timestamp}) 
CREATE (s)-[:BY {context:context.uid,timestamp:s.timestamp}]->(u) 
CREATE (s)-[:IN {user:u.id,timestamp:s.timestamp}]->(context)  
WITH u, s, context, statement 
FOREACH (conceptName in statement.uniqueconcepts |  
MERGE (c:Concept {name:conceptName}) ON CREATE SET c.uid=apoc.create.uuid() 
CREATE (c)-[:BY {context:context.uid,timestamp:s.timestamp,statement:s.suid}]->(u) 
CREATE (c)-[:OF {context:context.uid,user:u.uid,timestamp:s.timestamp}]->(s)  
CREATE (c)-[:AT {user:u.uid,timestamp:s.timestamp,context:context.uid,statement:s.uid}]->(context)  )  
WITH u, s 
UNWIND $conceptsRelations as conceptsRelation MATCH (c_from:Concept{name: conceptsRelation.from}) MATCH (c_to:Concept{name: conceptsRelation.to}) 
CREATE (c_from)-[:TO {context:conceptsRelation.context,statement:conceptsRelation.statement,user:u.uid,timestamp:conceptsRelation.timestamp, uid:apoc.create.uuid(), gapscan:conceptsRelation.gapscan, weight: conceptsRelation.weight}]->(c_to)  
RETURN DISTINCT s.uid
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError
Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof
```

Anybody knows why it's coming up? My `params` seem to be set correctly, I didn't see they couldn't be used in this way... Thanks!

Comment: If this were my problem I would use the divide and conquer approach. Split the statement apart then test, those parts that fail, split again and retry. Continue until you get the smallest parts that fail and then you should know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem is here:

```
...
FOREACH (conceptName in statement.uniqueconcepts |  
MERGE (c:Concept {name:conceptName})
...
```

`uniqueconcepts` in your parameter is a list of objects, not a list of strings, so when attempting to MERGE conceptName, it errors out as conceptName isn't a primitive type (or array or primitive types). I think you'll want to use `uniqueConcept` instead of `conceptName`, and in your MERGE use `name:uniqueConcept.name`. Check for other usages of the elements of statement.uniqueconcepts.

Comment: Nice catch! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 5):

This answer is for other n00bs like me that are trying to put a composite datatype into a property without reading the friendly manual, and get the error above. Google points here, so I felt appropriate to add this answer.

Specifically, I wanted to store a list `[(datetime, event), ...]` of tuples into a property of a relation.

Potential encountered errors are:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof

Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: Neo4j only supports a subset of Cypher types for storage as singleton or array properties. Please refer to section cypher/syntax/values of the manual for more details.
```

The bottom line is well summarized in [this forum post](https://community.neo4j.com/t/cant-create-a-node-with-nested-sub-properties/1744/4) by a Neo4j staff member:

> Neo4j doesn't allow maps as properties (no sub-properties allowed, basically), and though lists are allowed as properties, they cannot be lists of maps (or lists of lists for that matter).

Basically I was trying to bypass the natural functionality of the DB. There seem to be 2 workarounds:

1. Dig your heels in as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52491585/4511978), and store the property as e.g. a JSON string
2. Rethink the design, and model these kind of properties into the graph (i.e. being more specific with the nodes)

After a little rethinking I came up with a much simpler data model that didn't require composite properties in relations. Although option 1 may have its uses, when we have to insist against a well-designed system (which neo4j *is*), that is usually an indicator that we should change course.
Andres

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue, while adding the data into the Neo4j.

In my case I am trying to put a object(which has properties). And after converting into the JSON, it is a Map representation.

So it wont allow me to add the data. So I convert it into a flat map like "key.property" form and then add the data into the DB.